# Get the value of an output screen field

Tags: vba, rows, sap-gui

In view of counting how many rows I have in my table, I usually export it via VBA in excel then count the rows. Is there any way to get it directly from SAP GUI?

I tried to get it by `.VerticalScrollbar.Maximum`, but unless I don't use it properly, it didn't give me the right number...

```
ScrollBar = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr").VerticalScrollbar.Maximum
MsgBox ("ScrollBar= " & ScrollBar)
```

In other words:

In this filed I have 316 rows (counted with the excel export); `.VerticalScrollbar.Maximum` gives me 267 rows. Where are the 49 rows left in my count ?
[image]

I also found out that that this "information" button [image] make this window appear:

[image]

And these two numbers make the 316 I'm looking for: 395-79 = 316
So I tried to interact with this window while recording a macro and it only saves this interaction:

```
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/sub/1[0,0]/sub/1/6[0,10]/sub/1/6/8[0,14]/lbl[28,14]").setFocus
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/sub/1[0,0]/sub/1/6[0,10]/sub/1/6/8[0,14]/lbl[28,14]").caretPosition = 0
```

No way to copy these numbers...

**Edit: clarifactions**

Thanks for reading and have a good day!

Comment: The documentation of GuiLabel objects indicates that you can use the property Text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
session.findById("wnd[1]/usr/sub/1[0,0]/sub/1/6[0,10]/sub/1/6/8[0,14]/lbl[28,14]").text
```

Worked well.

@sandra-rossi : Thanks !